# TbDetailView Custom Attribute GetStatusName

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions

In trying to use my model function `GetStatusName` on `TbDetailView`, but its not working.
Its working properly on `TbGridView`.

Model Function:

```
public function getStatusName()
{
    switch($this->status)
    {
        case self::STATUS_ACTIVE:
            return 'Active';
            break;
        case self::STATUS_DELETED:
            return 'Deleted';
            break;
        default:
            return 'Unknown';
            break;
    }
}
```

Code:

```
<?php
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbDetailView',array(
    'type'=>'bordered condensed',
    'data'=>$model,
    'attributes'=>array(
        'name',
        array('name' => 'status', 'type' => 'text', 'value' => '$data->statusName'),
    ),
));
?>
```

View:

```
Name    John
Gender  $data->statusName
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `CDetailView`, `value` has to be specified directly without quotes. The value is not eval'd like in `CGridView`, so use :

```
array('name' => 'status', 'type' => 'text', 'value' => $model->statusName)
```

Comment: Yii Error: Undefined variable: data

Comment: oops hadn't seen your code before completely, it should be `$model`, basically you directly call the function with whatever model object you have passed to your view. Updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbDetailView',array(
   'type'=>'bordered condensed',
   'data'=>$model,
   'attributes'=>array(
       'name',
       array('name' => 'status', 'type' => 'text', 'value' => $data->statusName),
   ),
));
?>
```

or:

```
<?php
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbDetailView',array(
   'type'=>'bordered condensed',
   'data'=>$model,
   'attributes'=>array(
       'name',
       array('name' => 'status', 'type' => 'text', 'value' => getStatusName($data->getStatusName)),
   ),
));
?>
```

edited after coment.

Comment: There is not a relational property. See the original post (Updated).

Comment: First Option: Yii Error: Undefined variable: data

Comment: Second Option: Fatal error: Call to undefined function getStatusName()

Answer (score 2):

here is a small example, i found out right now how to work with formatting values:

```
    <?php $this -> widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbDetailView', array(
            'data' => $user,
            'type' => 'bordered striped condensed',
            'attributes' => array(
                    'name',
                    array(
                            'name' => 'birthDate',
                            'value' => Yii::app()->dateFormatter->format("dd.MM.yy", strtotime('$data->birthDate')),
                    ),
                    'code',
            ),
    ));
    ?>
```